# Why aren't strings stored in respective arrays?

Tags: c

File looks like this:

```
trying to read this file#*)will it work?
```

`string` and `string2` have some garbage whenever I try to read them; I'm guessing my `sscanf` is wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[100];
    char string[100];
    char string2[100];

    FILE *ptr = fopen ("testing8.txt", "r");

    if ((ptr = fopen("testing8.txt", "r"))!= NULL )
        printf("file opened successfuly\ncontinuing program..\n");
    else
    {
        printf("unable to open file, terminating program\n");
        return 0;
    }   

    fgets(buffer, 50, ptr);
    //testing to see whether string contains the string or not..

    printf("%s\n",buffer);

    sscanf(ptr,"%[^#*)]#*)%[^?]?", string, string2);
    puts(string);
    puts("\n");

    puts(string2);
    puts("\n");

    fclose(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you `fopen()` the same file twice?

Comment: Also, you would do well to compare the result of [`sscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) against the number of arguments you're trying to parse *before* assuming they parsed correctly. **Check your API result codes.**

Comment: You don't need `fopen` twice and there is a mistake on `sscanf` line. First argument should be `buffer` and not `ptr`.

Comment: thanks man i made an error by mistake

Answer (score 1):

If you try compiling your version of code, you should get the warning

```
$gcc so_test2.c 
so_test2.c: In function ‘main’:
so_test2.c:28: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘sscanf’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/stdio.h:452: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘struct FILE *’
$
```

So, i made the following changes. This works for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
        char buffer[100];
        char string[100];
        char string2[100];

        FILE *ptr;//fopen ("testing8.txt", "r");

        if ((ptr = fopen("testing8.txt", "r"))!= NULL )
                printf("file opened successfuly\ncontinuing program..\n");
        else
        {
                printf("unable to open file, terminating program\n");
                return 0;
        }

        if (fgets(buffer, 50, ptr) == NULL)  //added check for success of fgets()
        {
                printf("fgets error\n");
                exit (-1);
        }
        //testing to see whether string contains the string or not..

        printf("%s\n",buffer);

        sscanf(buffer,"%[^#*)]#*)%[^?]?", string, string2); //change ptr to buffer
        puts(string);
        puts("\n");

        puts(string2);
        puts("\n");

        fclose(ptr);
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: You've fixed the obvious errors — the one that prevents it compiling, and the double open.  You've not really addressed testing `fgets()` or `sscanf()`, both of which are important.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for pointing out. Updated check for `fgets()`

Answer (score 0):

Your code should read something like (fixing the blatant, non-compiling bug that had `ptr` instead of `buffer` in the call to `sscanf()`):

```
if (sscanf(buffer, "%[^#*)]#*)%[^?]?", string, string2) != 2)
    ...report format error...
```

Note that this expects to find the sequence `#*)` in the input buffer (as in your sample line).  These lines would work, fail, and work respectively:

```
OK#*)This is valid?
Not OK#This is invalid?
OK#*)You won't be able to tell that this is invalid!
```

If you wanted any one of the three punctuators to match, then you'd need to use:

```
"%[^#*)]%*1[#*)]%[^?]?"
```

The `*` between `%` and `[` suppresses the assignment.

There is no way to tell whether trailing context (such as the question mark) was recognized or not, at least, not without modifying the `sscanf()` format string and argument list:

```
char qmark;
if (sscanf(buffer, "%[^#*)]#*)%[^?]%[?]", string, string2, &qmark) != 3)
    ...report format error...
```

You should also check that `fgets()` actually returned a line:

```
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), ptr) == 0)
    ...report EOF or error...
```

I'd often recommend using length-limited conversion specifiers:

```
char qmark;
if (sscanf(buffer, "%99[^#*)]#*)%99[^?]%[?]", string, string2, &qmark) != 3)
    ...report format error...
```

but since the source string (`buffer`) is the same length, you can't run into a buffer overflow here.  Note that if the buffer is of size 100, you must specify 99 in the format string; it will write a null over the 100<sup>th</sup> character if necessary.